# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2^n)x^{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^nx^{n^2}$

I will use the Root test, let $c_n = 2^nx^{n^2}$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  c_{n}^{1/n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 2x^{n} = 0 $ if $-1<x<1$ and $\pm \infty$ if $|x|>1$

Since we want $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  c_{n}^{1/n}<1$ for convergence as according to the Root test, so the radius of convergence must be $1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I guess you are taking the limsup, but the result looks ok.

Comment: Thank you for confirming!

Comment: I would take $\lim |c_n|^{1/n}$ instead of $\lim c_n^{1/n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct: however you can calculate the radius of convergence of the series directly, by using the definition, i.e. for a given power series
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty c_m x^m
\quad\text{ we have }\quad
\limsup_{m\to \infty}\sqrt[m]{|c_m|}=\frac{1}{R}
$$
**But if you chose this way, you should be careful**: precisely, *you should consider the coefficients of the powers of $x$ which are different from $0$* and calculate the their root respect to the *exponent of their associated power*. Considering your series this means 
$$
c_m=
\begin{cases}
2^n&\text{ if }m=n^2\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{R}&=\limsup_{m\to \infty}\sqrt[m]{|c_m|}=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n^2]{2^n}\\
&=\limsup_{n\to\infty}2^\frac{n}{n^2}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}2^\frac{1}{n}\\
&=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{2} =1
\end{split} \implies R=1
$$

Comment: This helped me a lot thank you!

Comment: if you don't mind, would you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103554/radius-of-convergence-sum-n-0-infty-a-n-xn2-where-a-0-1-and-a-n-3

Comment: @Abhay I’ll have a look at it.