# Radius of convergence of series $\sum a_n x^{n^2}$ such that $a_0=1$ and $a_n=3^{-n}a_{n-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> My aim is to find the radius of convergence of the series $\sum a_n x^{n^2}$ such that $a_0=1$ and $a_n=3^{-n}a_{n-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

I will use the Ratio test, let $c_n=a_nx^{n^2}$

$$\lim \frac{c_n}{c_{n-1}} = \lim \frac{a_n\cdot x^{n^2}}{a_{n-1}\cdot x^{(n-1)^2}} = \lim \frac{x^{2n-1}}{3^{n}}$$

Now to find $\lim \frac{x^{2n-1}}{3^{n}}$, I will use the Root test

$$\lim |\frac{x^{2n-1}}{3^{n}}|^{\frac1n}=\frac{x^2}{3} $$

if $\frac{x^2}{3}<1 $ or $|x|<\sqrt{3}$ $  \;\Rightarrow \frac{x^{2n-1}}{3^{n}}\to 0 $

and if if $\frac{x^2}{3}>1 $ or $|x|>\sqrt{3} \Rightarrow \frac{x^{2n-1}}{3^{n}} \to \infty$

Since from the Ratio test, we need $\lim \frac{x^{2n-1}}{3^{n}}<1$ Hence the given series will converge if $|x|<\sqrt{3}$. So radius of convergence must be $R=\sqrt{3}$. However, my professor told us that the radius of convergence will be $\infty$. Can someone please tell me which is the correct answer and where did I go wrong in my explanation?

Comment: $R=\sqrt 3$ seems to be the right answer.

Comment: If $a_0=1$ and $a_n=3^{-n}a_{n-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ then indeed the series $\sum a_n x^n$ has infinite radius of convergence. But not the series $\sum a_n x^{n^2}$.

Comment: @Did $\sum a_n x^n$ has infinite radius of convergence, that is clear. But did I calculate the ROC of given series correctly?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: both of you thanks for confirming

Comment: My Apologies to everybody. I should have read carefully the answer and I should have checked my calculations. @Abhay, your calculations are right.

Comment: Thank you $$..$$